# How to convert received audio to udp packets?

Tags: iphone, ios, udp

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[dictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[dictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
```

I take input using `AVAudioRecorder` object, and I need to convert it to udp packets. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) is a nice library that contains a class called AsyncUdpSocket which is an Obj-C wrapper around the lower-level socket API.

After including AsyncUdpSocket just add this in header:

```
AsyncUdpSocket *socket;
```

And in main:

```
NSData *data  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:YourURL];//Convert Recieved Audio into NSData
[socket sendData:data toHost:@"192.168.x.x" port:5002 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

When testing don't forget to allow UDP communication on your server firewall!

Comment: i want to send the live voice as it is to another device so how to do it. As you have mentioned dataWithContentsOfURL,so do you mean that i should store it in file and then send it?But i dont want that.